# RxJava Realm findFirstAsync() result is not loaded, findFirst() fires endlessly

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

Why does this code endlessly execute it's .subscribe(..) part? I assumed that event will be fired only once, when matching Content object will be found. But it starts over and over again.

```
realm.where(Content.class)
                .equalTo("keyID", id)
                .findFirst()
                .<Content>asObservable()
                .map(this::getPostFromContent)
                .subscribe(post -> {
                    loadComments(post.getId());
                });
```

And if I change to .findFirstAsync() it throws an exception:
"Can't access a row that hasn't been loaded, make sure the instance is loaded by calling RealmObject.isLoaded()"

I am using latest version of realm.

**UPDATE**

I was able to make this work by using:

```
realm.where(RealmWrappedContent.class)
                .equalTo("keyID", id)
                .findFirstAsync()
                .<RealmWrappedContent>asObservable()
                .filter(post -> post.isLoaded())
                .first()
                .map(this::getPostFromContent)
                .subscribe(post -> {
                    loadComments(post.getId());
                });
```

But that's way too many thing you need to write just to use realm objects as observables. Is there any better way?

Comment: I'd assume you are getting an event in the first case each time the Realm underneath changes, btw read the [docs on using `asObservable()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#asObservable--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is submitting each time there is an update. In that case you need to use `filter/first` to only get 1 item as you found out.

If you want to change that behaviour in your entire app, you can also provide your own `RxObservableFactory` implementation as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#rxjava.

The default factory is called `RealmObservableFactory` and it should be fairly easy to either wrap that or provide your own implementation that does what your want for all observables.